# How to remove div for particular links

Tags: css, html

My website is a simple one using images. The whole site content is based on the menu's div tags. I added link using  tag and created separate hover effects for it using different , now what happens is when i hover that link the same hover effect that appears for menu occurs and the hover i created for the link doesn't work. I can close menu's div only at the last[as the alignment is getting changed if i close the menu's div before the link and use a different div for the link]. Please suggest a solution, if u want me to post the code to make it clear please tell it. Thank you.!

Answer (score 2):

its best to make sure that your making sure the pseudo-class is specific to a certain node. This can be achieved by going :

```
#(div name) a:hover {
   color: blue;
   text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

it'll ensure that the a attribute nested inside of the specific div is being referenced.

Comment: thanks for your response, but didn't work though :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector, to select particular link, or type of link, based on what's in markup: Here's example:

```
a[href="www.yoursite.com"]:hover { color: red; }
```

You can take any attribute that's inside your html tag, to select (id, class, href, title, alt etc. even made up attributes). 
You can take it step further, by using ,,similar'' operator, which selects element based on, if specified phrase exists in the attribute (but it's not exactly same). For example:

```
a[href~="https"]:hover { color: red; }
```

Will select all links with https inside href atribute.
Remember, that attirbute selector isn't suported in ie6, and is problematic in ie7, keep that in mind, you can look for workaround easly tho.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but didn't work though :(